# C# Difference between using Missing.Value and just leaving out the optional parameter from method call?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

So, after extensively searching, I found a lot of information about what the Missing.Value does passing the default value to an optional parameter.

But somehow not a single mention about why is it more useful, than just leaving out the optional parameter alltogether in which case, it also gets it's default value.

Came across it in a Ms Office interop code sample, but tried leaving it out, and works all the same, just as excpected, so, what gives?

E.g. in :

```
oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add( Missing.Value );
```

vs

```
oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Add();
```

Comment: If the method has many optional parameters, you can use it to skip specific ones.

Comment: AFAIK, COM interface does not support named parameters. If you have multiple optional parameters, and you want to skip one or two and pass the later ones, you will need to pass `Missing.Value` as the parameters you want to skip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify benifit of Optional/Named parameters with different example because `oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add( Missing.Value );` is already shared.

**Missing.Value**

> (From Remarks) Use this instance of the Missing class to represent missing values, for example, when you invoke methods that have default parameter values.

Example from [Missing Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.missing(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    public class MissingClass
    {
        public static void MethodWithDefault(int value = 33)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("value = {0}", value);
        } 
    }

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      // Invoke without reflection
      MissingClass.MethodWithDefault();

      // Invoke by using reflection.
      Type t = typeof(MissingClass);
      MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("MethodWithDefault");
      mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { Missing.Value });
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       value = 33  
//       value = 33
```

**Optional Parameter**, See following example ,if caller of this method(`GetBillingInfo`) does not supply values for those parameters then the default value provided to the parameters will be used

You will be able to call your method by 4 ways

```
GetBillingInfo();//No parametes (kValue,quoteID)
GetBillingInfo("kvalue"); // KValue
GetBillingInfo("KValue" , 20); // kvalue + quoteID
```

You can call it with paramName (Named Parameters)

```
GetBillingInfo(quoteID: 20) //quoteID
```

Read [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)

Comment: Just giving OP an idea of Optional/Named parameters as per in question details `not a single mention about why is it more useful, than just leaving out the optional parameter alltogether in which case, it also gets it's default value`

Comment: I've never thought about using `Missing.Value` outside of com Interop. Only now that I saw your comment I thought about writing back that using the `Missing.Value` is for dealing with Com Interop, but I thought I'd better check first - seems like I was wrong. The documentation for `Missing.Value` does not limit it in anyway to com interop. In fact, it has a .net framework code sample. So first - Thank you. I would have never guessed that, and Second, That puts your answer in a better context. Seems like my first comment was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion is well-founded. In this day and age, there *is* no real use for `Missing.Value`. But in the dark ages before C# 4.0 (2010, I think?), optional parameters were not yet a feature of the C# language.

This means that if you wanted to work with COM Interop interfaces that relied on optional parameters and exposed a large number of such parameters - with Office interop being a prime example, you either had to pass `Missing.Value` for each argument you didn't want (over 15, for some calls!) or use VB.NET to write a wrapper around the COM calls. VB.NET was explicitly designed to support this sort of COM interop, as it was a common use for VB before it.

But today? Just drop the optional params.

More info can be found in this old answer to a related question:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185186/com-interop-support-which-is-better-c-or-vb/185191#185191