# Delete before last column in excel

Tags: c#, excel-interop

This code will delete the last column. It's working fine:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range last = xlWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);      
last.EntireColumn.Delete(Missing.Value);
```

However, if I combine the code above with the code below:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range last1 = xlWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
last1.EntireColumn.Delete(Missing.Value);
```

..the codes combined are going to delete 1 column instead of two. Why?

My logic is that If I delete the last column and then try to get the new LastCell again and delete, It will delete 2 but that's not happening for some reason.

Comment: Can you put the code in the order you have it?

Comment: @Haytam Well, It's the same order I wrote it. The two first lines, then the second two lines. Exactly that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the value of `xlCellTypeLastCell` will stay the same <strike>until the workbook is closed and reopened</strike> *(it can be reset programmatically. See the "update" section below)*. You can make sure of that by checking the value of `last1.Column`, you'll notice that it's the same as `last.Column`.

This behavior can also be observed manually in Excel itself. Try deleting a column *manually* in Excel and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>. You will notice that the activated cell is still in the empty column. What `xlCellTypeLastCell` does is emulate the behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>.

Instead, you can use a different method that gets the last used column. Something like this should work:

First, add this line on top of the file to simplify the namespace:

```
using MSOffice = Microsoft.Office.Interop;
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
MSOffice.Excel.Range last = 
    xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(What: "*", After: xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1], 
                           SearchOrder: MSOffice.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, 
                           SearchDirection: MSOffice.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious);
last.EntireColumn.Delete();

MSOffice.Excel.Range last1 =
    xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(What: "*", After: xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1],
                           SearchOrder: MSOffice.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,
                           SearchDirection: MSOffice.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious);
last1.EntireColumn.Delete();
```

Note: Because newer versions of C# (Since C# 4.0) support optional parameters, you don't have to use `Missing.Value` [*unless you're using a version prior to C# 4.0*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48249887/4934172).

---

### Update:

Looks like there's a way to reset the value of the last cell retrieved by the first method, and that's by calling `Worksheet.UsedRange`. Therefore, you can still use your method if you prefer to, but you'd have to reset the value each time:

```
MSOffice.Excel.Range last = 
    xlWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(MSOffice.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);
last.EntireColumn.Delete();

var dummy = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

MSOffice.Excel.Range last1 = 
    xlWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(MSOffice.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);
last1.EntireColumn.Delete();
```

Comment: Both codes worked! Thank you for taking time to write all of this in details.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should just use For Loop do delete how many columns you want.
Something like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  last.EntireColumn.Delete(Missing.Value);
}
```

didnt tested this yet but hope this works :) You get the idea

Comment: This will not work. You never changed the value of `last`, how do you expect it to refer to (or delete) a different column?